# adding a *local* function to an existing R-package

Tags: r, bash, extension-methods, r-package

Many great R packages exists. However, often they use slightly different names for the same behaviour. As I often use different packages, the different names get in my way. Thus, I would like to extend the original package by adding **local** functions. E.g.

1. in the package "rethinking" we use the function "extract.samples()" to obtain the samples from the posterior distribution.
2. in the package "rstanarm" we use the function "as.matrix()" instead.

It would be nice to add the function "extract.samples()" to my **local** repository, and to define that it is called **only if the input parameter is an "rstanarm object"**.  Thus, I really would like to extend the package: If I load "rethinking" the "rethinking::extract.samples()" is used, and if I load "rstanarm" the function "rstanarm::extract.samples()" is used.

What I currently do is the following:

```
extract.samples = function(object, n=1000, ...){     
    if ( class(object)[[1]] == 'stanreg' ){
        # rstanarm object:
        SIMULATIONS = as.matrix(object)
    } else if ( attr(class(object), "package") == 'rethinking' ){
        SIMULATIONS = rethinking::extract.samples(object, n=n, ...)
    }
    
    return(invisible( SIMULATIONS ))
}
```

Thus, I explicitly have to take care of all the possible objects and parameter setting. This becomes messy, if a third package defines the function "extract.samples" or if the two packages use different parameters. I wonder, if there is a more robust method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to create your own package that exports a generic function and several methods for it.  If you can edit `rethinking`, then just do that, otherwise create a third package.  I'll assume you're doing that.

Here's what the code could look like:

```r
extract.samples <- function(x, ...) {
   UseMethod("extract.samples")
}

extract.samples.stanreg <- function(x, ...) {
   as.matrix(x, ...)
}

extract.samples.default <- function(x, ...) {
   rethinking::extract.samples(x, ...)
}
```